# Git push the code to master using tag of local branch

Tags: git, github

I have a feature branch. Once tested I create tags. I want to push the code to master branch using the tag. Is there any way?

Comment: I’ma little confused. A tag is a pointer to a specific commit and is unaffected by merges or rebases like a branch. What do you mean by _”push the code to master branch using the tag”_?

Comment: Just in case..... i have answered the technical question.... but it reeeeeally begs the question: why do you create a tag in the first place?

Comment: A tag points to a commit. What you push is always a commit. If you want to push the commit be specifying the tag, then sure, push it. What's the difficulty? But the usual thing is to push a branch _and_ any tags reachable from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try with: `git push origin the-tag:master`..... and if we want to be absolutely sure that git won't create a tag called `master` (say.... it's a real repo with real work being done by a lot of people so we don't want to mess up), you would try: `git push origin the-tag:refs/heads/master`.... but I am inclined to think that the first proposal should work.